# OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support

Tags: opencv, c++11, homebrew, yolo, darknet

I'm trying to compile [Yolo/darknet](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) with OpenCV on my macOS 10.14.3 (Mojave). Here is basically what I did:

I installed OpenCV via `brew install opencv` and it gave me version 4.1.0 (confirmed via `opencv_version`).

Per docs, `./darknet imtest data/eagle.jpg` works fine so I know OpenCV installed somewhat successfully. Next, I try to `make` darknet again.

At first it complained about not finding opencv.pc, but I made a symlink `opencv.pc` to point to `opencv4.pc` in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/`.

But now it complains about the following:

```
[hobbes3@hobbes3-4] ~/darknet $ make
g++ -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DOPENCV -c ./src/image_opencv.cpp -o obj/image_opencv.o
In file included from ./src/image_opencv.cpp:5:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.1.0_2/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.1.0_2/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp:52:
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.1.0_2/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvdef.h:666:4: fatal error: "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support"
#  error "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support"
   ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [obj/image_opencv.o] Error 1
```

What do I need to do next?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just try to go punk and manually edit CXX flags in `Makefile`.

If you look on [line 30](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/Makefile#L30) in current version, you could add `-std=c++11` and see what happens when you run make again. Remember to do `make clean` first.

C++11 is mostly backwards compatible, so it may just work.

Answer (score 1):

I add it ,but get this error:
cc1: warning: command line option ‘-std=c++11’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C